# Unable to create release build after adding play services(with proguard)

Tags: android, google-play-services, proguard, android-proguard

After I added compile `'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.+'` to my project I can't generate release apk anymore.

**Also, my `Proguard_rules.pro` is below:**

```
-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview { public *;}

-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }

-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**

-keep class com.pushwoosh.** { *; }

-dontwarn com.pushwoosh.**

-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

-keep class com.parse.*{ *; }

-dontwarn com.parse.**

-dontwarn com.squareup.picasso.**

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * { native <methods>;}

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.ads.** { public *;}

-keep public class com.google.ads.** { public *;}

-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle { protected Object[][] getContents();}

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable { public static final *** NULL;} 

-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *

-keepclassmembernames class * { @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;}

-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable { public static final ** CREATOR;}

-keep class com.shephertz.** {*;}
```

**How to fix this error?!**

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexRelease'.>com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? such as, Specifying the version like: `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'`? as mentioned here? https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup it should fix the error, Otherwise, i can assure you i've seen the same question before.

Comment: When I do that I received this error! Error:(28, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0
<a href="install.m2.repo">Install Repository and sync project</a><br><a href="openFile:D:/apps/app_name/app/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>

Comment: Cannot download that since we are blocked from that server, you need to change your ip and then try.

Comment: Okay So I should download it and after that my problem will be solved right?

Comment: I hope so :) If it didn't work, try to click on `Install Repository and sync project` (after changing the ip) then it should work.and it seems, that needs a `Repository` (`i think -> called Google Repository`) after installing that, it should work.

Comment: Okay I`ll work on it.Thank you so much

Comment: You're welcome, let me know if any success achieved.

Comment: It works! You Solved my problem! really thanks

Comment: I just posted an answer, glad to help.goodluck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, try this:

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'`

And try to change your ip to an another country because we or (iran's ip) is blocked for the reasons.

And like i said, after that you need to click on `Install Repository and sync project`
For installing the specific(or needed) package.